# Add objectAtIndex: 1 -9 when exists from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I want to get a few objects out of an `NSDictionary`

10 at a time, so objectAtIndex 0 to 9

Now addings with just:

```
AddObject:[[[json objectForKey:@"one"] objectAtIndex:1] ObjectForKey:@"likes"];
```

and that 9 times, is there a simpler way to do this, and only add when object exists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate - what's the structure if this dictionary? It seems as though you're pulling data out of a dictionary, within an array, within a dictionary

Comment: I am using this API - : http://dribbble.com/api - look at the /shots/:list section

Comment: Don't see a "one" key. Not a "likes" key either

Comment: ooh sorry that was an example. It is @"shots" and @"views_count"

Comment: OK so "shots" is an array and "views_count" is an NSNumber. What exactly are you trying to do with these objects?

Comment: just displaying them, I am working on a custom dribbble app, and want to get an array of views_count, and infinite scrolling, so it adds 10 objects at a time when they exist

Comment: So your question is actually related to paging content within a UITableView, not how to extract data correctly from parsed JSON. Please try to explain the issue in depth and we'll try to assist.

Comment: No, Paging is working, but now I have 10 rows of text and it doesn't check wheter there are shots or aren't, checking doesn't work for me with if([json objed.....]) { } - so It just shows sigabrt when there arent more posts

Comment: At least post the code that you use for obtaining this json - is it parsed or raw?

Comment: It is parsed, like on the dribbble api page.

Comment: This had worked all the time: "[LikesList addObject:[[[json objectForKey:@"shots"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"likes_count"]];

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *shotsArr = [json objectForKey:@"shots"];
NSMutableArray *allViewsCounts = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *shotDict in shotsArr) {
    NSNumber *viewsCount = [shotDict objectForKey:@"views_count"];
    [allViewsCounts addObject:viewsCount];
}
```

if you wish for only 10 objects in this array:

```
__block NSMutableArray *allViewsCounts = [NSMutableArray array];
[shotsArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *shotDict = obj;
    NSNumber *viewsCount = [shotDict objectForKey:@"views_count"];
    [allViewsCounts addObject:viewsCount];
    if (idx == 10) {
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

Comment: Struggled upon a problem, It adds 10 at a time, but the next page, (parsed JSON again) needs to extend the array so we have 20 items, How can I fix that, it replaces it right now, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, just add them to the existing array without initializing it.

Comment: I don't initialise them, except for shotsArr, do I need to add objects to the shots array instead of replace the existing ones, I don't think so.

Comment: Of course, whatever is replaced in the array is lost. If you need 20 records, the array should contain 20 objects

Comment: My Bad, made a mistake on my site with checking Internet Connection :S

Answer (score 0):

Use simply for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
     if([[[json objectForKey:@"one"] objectAtIndex:i] ObjectForKey:@"likes"]){
          AddObject:[[[json objectForKey:@"one"] objectAtIndex:i] ObjectForKey:@"likes"];
     }
}
```

Comment: Getting errors when I use it in a for loop - No known instance for selector: ObjectForKey

Comment: The problem is `NSDictionary` structure. what is the structure of `NSDictionary. How you are parsing

Comment: Use NSLog to print the details of this statement `[[json objectForKey:@"one"] objectAtIndex:i]`

Comment: Other comment: "I am using this API - : dribbble.com/api - look at the /shots/:list section"